# Migration from Sharepoint 2007 to 2010

Tags: 2007, content-editor-web-part

Currently I work on a subsite from the SP 2007 farm. But in the upcoming future the parent site plans on upgrading to sharepoint 2010 and I wonder how will this effect my subsite. In my subsite I have a lot of custom webparts built with javascript and some jquery. Im trying to understand if my subsite inherits this 2010 deployment and what changes for my subsite, will it change the DOM of my pages so dramatically that my custom code on the pages wont function properly. If so how should I prepare for this and also is there any way I can avoid this?

Thanks,

**Edit-** Also, doesn't SP Designer come integrated within 2010 unlike 2007, so in order to do custom web parts I would need visual studio?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Designer 2010 is not integrated with SharePoint Server 2010. You have to download it:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d88a1505-849b-4587-b854-a7054ee28d66&displaylang=en

You don't **need** to have visual studio 2010 to build web parts, but it will make it a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to upgrade to the new Layout (Ribbon etc.) you can set your SubWebs to NOT inherit the new Layout.
You can then upgrade to 2010 and check if your WebParts are working, if not keep the 2007 layout. This can be done by settings the UIVersion of the SPWeb (more info:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662217.aspx) or in the site settings. Via the object model it can also be undone (which is not possible via site settings).

Even more info about upgrading to SP2010: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ff420377

Answer (score 0):

This is partly covered here: [Developing WebParts for SP 2007 and SP 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1344/developing-webparts-for-sp-2007-and-sp-2010)

Comment: well in some of my custom code I call tags using idnames and class names, and my idea is that would most likely not work in 2010 being that the DOM will be arraganed differently?

Answer (score 0):

The DOM changes significantly, it switches to a div based layout.  You may need to rewrite code as a result depending on how you are selecting elements for modification.  Most likely they aren't going to be doing an inplace upgrade, so talk to your folks handling this and see if you can test your site out after the test upgrade is complete.  Your customizations are not likely to be flagged by the preupgrade check, so they won't know that your site will have issues.

You will then see what is broken and will give you time to adjust your scripts accordingly.